# How to get value as java.lang.Object from Gson?

Tags: java, gson

I have to fetch value from list of `com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive` and put it in `List<java.lang.Object>`.
I don't know actual type of objects.
Later on  some other API will do `instanceOf` check to get proper data type.

But `JsonPrimitive` class above does not return object. I can call `isNumber`, but that returns a `LazilyParsedNumber`.
Which does not provide `isInt` etc methods, or access to object so I can call `isInstance` on it.

EDIT: I have done, `getAsDouble`. that should work for all except `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`
EDIT2: Since json only has a number data type, it cannot differentiate between float, short, Int, BigDecimal etc. Hence it seems user **has to know** target data type.

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Does `Object object = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Object.class);` not work?

Comment: So, a `LazilyParsedNumber` is still a `Number`, right? And it has all the methods of the type `Number`. You can get its value as a double, int, etc. Json as is doesn't differentiate between integers and floating point numbers.

Comment: Can you please show the JSON and Java code?

Comment: @Nico, I have a com.google.gson.JsonElement, which does not provide anything like you suggested. From com.google.gson.JsonElement I am fetching com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive

Comment: @RealSkeptic, to call floatValue() in Numbers I have to know that data is actually a float, which I dont.

Comment: In fact, you don't. It will give you the data as a float. If you expect `int` and `double`, then getting everything as `double` will be fine - and you convert from a `double` to an `int` if it's an integral number without loss of precision. If you also have `long` etc., you may lose precision on conversion, and then perhaps you'd do better if you retrieve the number as a `BigDecimal` to begin with, which Gson allows you. But the bottom line is - you don't have a way of distinguishing an integral number from a real number in Gson.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, if I had access to JsonPrimitive.value then calling isInstance on it, should get me actual data type, right ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, from the source. The `value` is exactly that `LazilyParsedNumber` if it comes from the default parsers.

Comment: @ZxcvMnb Wait a sec. You're saying that something (other than a primitive) is *not* an object?

Comment: Gson will make sure that what you are saving will get retrieved during deserialization. When it comes to numbers, It will not guarantee the exact data type. But there will not be any data loss